# ActiveRecord Find By Year, Day or Month on a Date field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord model that has a date attribute.  Is it possible to utilize that date attribute to find by Year, Day and Month:

```
Model.find_by_year(2012)
Model.find_by_month(12)
Model.find_by_day(1)
```

or is it simply possible to find_by_date(2012-12-1).

I was hoping I could avoid creating Year, Month and Day attributes.

Comment: I don't think I have communicated well.  What I'm trying do is be able to find records/objects by using the full date, the year only, the month only and the day only.   The first case is straightforward, its the later three (using month, day and year) that are giving me difficulty.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Assuming that your "date attribute" is a date (rather than a full timestamp) then a simple `where` will give you your "find by date":

```
Model.where(:date_column => date)
```

You don't want `find_by_date_column` as that will give at most one result.

For the year, month, and day queries you'd want to use the `extract` SQL function:

```
Model.where('extract(year  from date_column) = ?', desired_year)
Model.where('extract(month from date_column) = ?', desired_month)
Model.where('extract(day   from date_column) = ?', desired_day_of_month)
```

However, if you're using SQLite, you'd have to mess around with `strftime` since it doesn't know what `extract` is:

```
Model.where("cast(strftime('%Y', date_column) as int) = ?", desired_year)
Model.where("cast(strftime('%m', date_column) as int) = ?", desired_month)
Model.where("cast(strftime('%d', date_column) as int) = ?", desired_day_of_month)
```

The `%m` and `%d` format specifiers will add leading zeroes in some case and that can confuse the equality tests, hence the `cast(... as int)` to force the formatted strings to numbers.

ActiveRecord won't protect you from all the differences between databases so as soon as you do anything non-trivial, you either have to build your own portability layer (ugly but sometimes necessary), tie yourself to a limited set of databases (realistic unless you're releasing something that has to run on any database), or do all your logic in Ruby (insane for any non-trivial amount of data).

The year, month, and day-of-month queries will be pretty slow on large tables. Some databases let you add indexes on function results but ActiveRecord is too stupid to understand them so it will make a big mess if you try to use them; so, if you find that these queries are too slow then you'll have to add the three extra columns that you're trying to avoid.

If you're going to be using these queries a lot then you could add scopes for them but the [recommended way to add a scope with an argument](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments) is just to add a class method:

> Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes. These methods will still be accessible on the association objects...

So you'd have class methods that look like this:

```
def self.by_year(year)
    where('extract(year from date_column) = ?', year)
end
# etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer.   It seems to do this you have to rely upon database specfic function which defeats one of the benefits of activerecord.  Perhaps that's why you see dates broken out by month, day and year so often.  Thanks a again.

Comment: always impressed by the quality of your answers

Comment: This was really helpful, although for SQLite I had to `CAST` the date number to an integer instead of adding 0 (adding 0 gave me the wrong number for some reason). 
My revised filters are then:

```Model.where("CAST(strftime('%Y', date_column) as INT) = ?", desired_year)
Model.where("CAST(strftime('%m', date_column) as INT) = ?", desired_month)
Model.where("CAST(strftime('%d', date_column) as INT) = ?", desired_day_of_month)
```

Comment: @JayEl-Kaake: I think an explicit `cast(... as int)` is better than trickery in any case, I'm not sure why I didn't use `cast` in the first place.

Comment: No need for extract method in pg you can use `TO_CHAR` with `ILIKE` in only one line, I posted the full example at the end of this thread

Comment: but iam using sqlite3 how to do this

Comment: @giridharan There's a "However, if you're using SQLite, you'd have to mess around with `strftime` since it doesn't know what `extract` is" section already there.

Answer (score 34):

Database independent version ...

```
def self.by_year(year)
  dt = DateTime.new(year)
  boy = dt.beginning_of_year
  eoy = dt.end_of_year
  where("published_at >= ? and published_at <= ?", boy, eoy)
end
```

Comment: There's also `beginning_of_day`/`end_of_day` and `beginning_of_month`/`end_of_month` for the other implementations.

Comment: This is a far superior answer since it will use an index if available. Mu's will do a table scan.

Comment: `dt = DateTime.new(year)` is already the beginning of the year; you don't need the extra datetime. Eg, 

`boy = DateTime.new(year); eoy = boy.end_of_year`

Answer (score 12):

In your Model:

```
scope :by_year, lambda { |year| where('extract(year from created_at) = ?', year) }
```

In your Controller:

```
@courses = Course.by_year(params[:year])
```

Answer (score 11):

For MySQL try this out

```
Model.where("MONTH(date_column) = 12")
Model.where("YEAR(date_column) = 2012")
Model.where("DAY(date_column) = 24")
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Simple Implementation for Just The Year

**`app/models/your_model.rb`**

```
scope :created_in, ->( year ) { where( "YEAR( created_at ) = ?", year ) }
```

**Usage**

```
Model.created_in( 1984 )
```

Answer (score 6):

To look for all the records matching a specific day / month / year you could do:

```
Model.where(date: Date.today.all_day)
Model.where(date: Date.today.all_month)
Model.where(date: Date.today.all_year)
```

`.all_X` returns a date range:

```
 Time.current.all_year
=> Sat, 01 Jan 2022 00:00:00.000000000 UTC +00:00..Sat, 31 Dec 2022 23:59:59.999999999 UTC +00:00
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest way to do this is a scope:

```
scope :date, lambda {|date| where('date_field > ? AND date_field < ?', DateTime.parse(date).beginning_of_day, DateTime.parse(date).end_of_day}
```

Use it like this:

```
Model.date('2012-12-1').all
```

That will return all models with a date_field between the beginning and end of day for the date you send.

Comment: A day is not an open interval, it is a half-open interval.

Comment: `'d >= ? and d < ?', dt.beginning_of_day, dt.tomorrow.beginning_of_day`. Using `<` and `>` misses the boundary between days.

Comment: i am not quite sure this is something that Mutuelinvestor was asking for as it does not cover case when user is asking for all posts from April, neglecting 'year' part

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Model.where("MONTH(date_column) = ? and DAY(date_column) = ?", DateTime.now.month, DateTime.now.day)
```

Comment: @NarenP I don't think so. PostgreSQL haven't the `MONTH` function. Try extract or date_part. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/MONTH()_equivalent http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date_part/

Answer (score 1):

I like BSB's answer but as a scope

```
scope :by_year, (lambda do |year| 
  dt = DateTime.new(year.to_i, 1, 1)
  boy = dt.beginning_of_year
  eoy = dt.end_of_year
  where("quoted_on >= ? and quoted_on <= ?", boy, eoy)
end)
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be another one:

```
def self.by_year(year)
  where("published_at >= ? and published_at <= ?", "#{year}-01-01", "#{year}-12-31")
end
```

Works pretty well for me in SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

Another short scope as below:

```
  class Leave
    scope :by_year, -> (year) {
      where(date:
                Date.new(year).beginning_of_year..Date.new(year).end_of_year)
    }
  end
```

Call the scope:

```
Leave.by_year(2020)
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use:

```
Model.where('extract(month from birthday_column) = ? and extract(day from birthday_column) = ?', Time.now.month, Time.now.day)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for just the date, simply do:

```
Model.where(date: Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for `extract` method, this works like a charm in postgresql:

```
text_value = "1997" # or text_value = '1997-05-19' or '1997-05' or '05', etc
sql_string = "TO_CHAR(date_of_birth::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ILIKE '%#{text_value.strip}%'"
YourModel.where(sql_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Postgresql v 11+(i've tested): below way works

```
Model.where('extract(year  from date_column::date) = ?', desired_year)
Model.where('extract(month from date_column::date) = ?', desired_month)
Model.where('extract(day   from date_column::date) = ?', desired_day_of_month)
```