# Simple Rails Report with for a count within a month

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am producing a report where the user selects a month and the report shows the number of households that visited the agency during the Month stored as @month.

Each Household can have many visits with a visited_on attribute for the date of the visit. A Household may visit more than once in a month but I just want to know how many different households visited in the month

This is my best shot so far:

```
def house_count(month)
  where(housholds.visits.visited_on.strftime('%M') == month ).count
end
```

This method is in my controller for households and of course it doesn't work

How do I produce a report that show eg.   Month: June  Total Households seen: 45

Answer (score 0):

Move the code to the `Household` model:

```
class Household < ActiveRecord::Base

  def visits_count(month)
    visits.where("strftime('%m', visited_on) + 0 = ?", month).count
  end

end
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624601/activerecord-find-by-year-day-or-month-on-a-date-field) the `+ 0` helps with formatting.

Other options to try, depending on your database type:

```
where("extract(month from visited_on) = ?", month)
where("MONTH(visited_on) = ?", month)
```

Comment: OK but I get this error          `PG::Error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: "May"
LINE 1: ...ROM "visits"  WHERE (extract(month from visited_on) = 'May')
                                                                 ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "visits"  WHERE (extract(month from visited_on) = 'May')`

Comment: I think you have to use the month numbers, not names.

Comment: I figured it out with this `where("select(to_char(visited_on, 'FMMonth')) = ?", month)`

Answer (score 0):

I was unclear in the question but households have visits so I moved the the method to the visits table and used:

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base  

def self.by_month(month)
  where("select(to_char(visited_on, 'FMMonth')) = ?", month)
end
```

This gives me the number of visits per month - I still need to add DISTINCT for the household_id contained in the visits table so I am counting the different households in case a the same household visits twice