# Determine day in date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an activity model which has an activity date. Now I am iterating day numbers and I want to show the activity from a collection of activities which has that day number. Something like this:

```
1 activities = Activity.all
2 (1..31).each do |day|
3   activity = activities.where(activity_date.day == day)
4   unless activity.blank?
5     ..show activity data...
6   end
7 end
```

The issue is with line 3, which doesn't work obviously. What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: You can found your answer on a similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624601/activerecord-find-by-year-day-or-month-on-a-date-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySql [dayofmonth()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth) function:

```
activity = Activity.where("dayofmonth(created_at) = ?", day).first
```

Like this it will only fetch necessary records from db.

Note that even if you have more than one activities in that day it will only select the first one.