# Prettier ActiveRecord where query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have written a method to retrive all articles created within a given year.

```
def articles_for_year(year)
  from = Date.strptime("#{year}-01-01").to_datetime
  to = from.end_of_year
  where(created_at: from..to)
en
```

This method feels somewhat clunky and low-level. Can it be implemented in a nicer way?

Comment: Doesn't seem clunky or low level to me at all.

Comment: you should take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624601/activerecord-find-by-year-day-or-month-on-a-date-field)

Comment: I think your approach is write while @keymone has given the more `rails` way of   doing it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can convert it into scope with lambda:

```
class Article
  scope :in_year, -> {|year| where created_at: (year.beginning_of_year..year.end_of_year) }
end
```

i would argue that passing actual date argument is better than passing year integer but that's separate discussion

also you can use `Time.mktime` method to create date object, `strptime` is usually very slow