# Rails Controller Display Only Year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, controller

In my rails app I have a movies table, a movie has a release_date (date/month/year).

I also have a years table which will display all movies from a specific year
If i create the year 2013, I would like to display all movies from the year 2013

In my years controller, in the :show action, I have this

```
@movies = Movie.where(:release_date => :ynumber)
```

But it doesn't show any movies from that year, even though there are movies with a release_date 2013.

I assume that it isnt showing because when I call :release_date, it is displaying (date/month/year). How can I have it display ONLY `year`?

I've tried using `.strftime("%Y")` and `.strptime("%Y")` but these dont seem to work

PS:  I am using SQLite3 in development mode and PostgreSQL in production mode

Years#show

```
def show

    @year = Year.find(params[:id])

    #those i've tried seperately which havent worked
    @movies = Movie.where("extract(year from release_date) = ?", ynumber)
    @movies = Movie.where("extract(year from release_date) = ?", :ynumber)
    @movies = Movie.where("extract(year from release_date) = ?", 'ynumber')
    @movies = Movie.where("extract(year from release_date) = ?", ':ynumber')
    @movies = Movie.where("extract(year from release_date) = ?", params[:ynumber])



    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @year }
    end
  end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActiveRecord Find By Year, Day or Month on a Date field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624601/activerecord-find-by-year-day-or-month-on-a-date-field)

Answer (score 3):

To find all movies by year try this:

1) MySQL:

```
@movies = Movie.where("YEAR(release_date) = ?", 2013)
```

2) SQLite3:

```
@movies = Movie.where("strftime('%Y', release_date) = ?", 2013)
```

3) PostgreSQL:

```
@movies = Movie.where("extract(year from release_date) = ?", 2013)
```

Comment: But Year isnt a column in the Table. 

`SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: YEAR: SELECT "movies".* FROM "movies"  WHERE (YEAR(release_date) = '2013')
 `

Comment: Would the MySQL option work with PostgreSQL, sorry for not having specified the database. I'll edit.

Comment: I've pushed to Heroku and I get this error when going to a years' show page 
`@movies = Movie.where("extract(year from release_date) = ?", :ynumber)`

Comment: You pass year as parameter? If yes it must be `params[:ynumber]`, if it is variable try `ynumber` without ':'

Comment: None of these worked, i've tried

`params[:ynumber]`, which will load the page but not display the movies

`ynumber`, `:ynumber`, `'ynumber'`, which give a 500

Comment: Please show how you pass `ynumber`, I mean form and controller action.

Comment: Added it to the question

Comment: If `params[:id]` is year (for example 2013), you must `@movies = Movie.where("extract(year from release_date) = ?", @year)`, because no one knows what is `ynumber`, and I think in json you need all `@movies` so `format.json { render json: @movies }`

Comment: This Worked
`@movies = Movie.where("extract(year from release_date) = ?", @year.ynumber)`. Edit your answer and i'll accept

Answer (score 1):

You also can use release_date **.to_date.year** to get the year, since you have an standard format (date/month/year).

So you can filter using this, similar to Rajarshi Das's suggestion:

```
@movies = Movie.all.select{|mov| mov.release_date.to_date.year == params[:ynumber]}
```

OR

```
@movies = Movie.scoped.select{|mov| mov.release_date.to_date.year == params[:ynumber]}
```