# using a select, assign variable and retrieve records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date

I am attempting what I would think is simple, but I have had zero luck in finding a solution that is similar AND easily adaptable to my problem.

I have a view with a select dropdown which only contains months (January-December).  I want the user to be able to choose a month and click a link_to button and retrieve a subset of records where the billDate field contains the month in question, I don't care about the day, and the records will always be the current year.

I have used the following...

model...

```
class Bentry < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :billDate, :timeBilled, :expenseBilled, :client_id, :paid, :billTotal, :pmtTotal, :cPmtTotal, :tPmtTotal 

belongs_to :client
```

... view w/ select...

```
<p>
<%= form_tag("/bentries#monthlysumm", method: "get") do %>
<% @months = [{"month" => "January", "id" => "1"}, {"month" => "February", "id" => "2"}, {"month" => "March", "id" => "3"}, {"month" => "April", "id" => "4"}, {"month" => "May", "id" => "5"}, {"month" => "June", "id" => "6"}, {"month" => "July", "id" => "7"}, {"month" => "August", "id" => "8"}, {"month" => "September", "id" => "9"}, {"month" => "October", "id" => "10"}, {"month" => "November", "id" => "11"}, {"month" => "December", "id" => "12"} ] %>

<%= rpt_month = select_tag( 'months', options_for_select(@months.collect {|p| [ p['month'], p['id'] ] }) ) %>

<%= link_to "<button>Get Report</button>".html_safe, bentries_path(:billDate => rpt_month) %>

<% end %>
```

... and, controller...

```
def monthlysumm
   @bentries = Bentry.joins(:client).where("billDate = ?", params[:rpt_month])
end
```

Having never done this before, I don't understand how to get the value from the select passed to the GET call.  It appears to be passing the entire hash of months and ID's.  Secondly, am I doing the query correctly in the controller?  I only care to look at the month in the billDate field which is a complete date (NOT datetime), and retrieve all bills dated in the month selected.

I am very green when it comes to RoR, so if you need any further info just ask, but be specific... assume I knnow nothing!  ; )

**EDIT * ***
With aid from Nitish, I have gotten the select fixed and I am now passing the month variable to my controller.  And, also with a hand from Nitish, I have tried to apply the edits to the controller referenced in the other answer he references about querying based only on the Month portion of a date field.  BUT, I am still not returning any records AND I know I have entries with a "billDate" containing the month I selected.

**EDIT * ***
NEW edited controller for the app...

```
# GET /bentries/january
def monthlysumm
   @bentries = Bentry.by_month(params[:billDate])    
end
```

AND here is the addition to the model...

```
def self.by_month(mon)
   where("strftime('%m', billDate) + 0 = ?", mon)
end
```

This generates a SQL statement like this...

```
SELECT "bentries".* FROM "bentries" WHERE (strftime('%m", billDate) + 0 = '2')
```

If I go into SQLite Manager in Firefox and type (the equivalent) SQL statement of...

```
SELECT * FROM bentries WHERE (strftime('%m', billDate) + 0 = 2)
```

It returns the expected 3 records from the "bentries" table, but yet the code in app generates NO resulting recordset.

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong in the controller or model?!?

Comment: In combination with [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225551/query-in-rails-not-returning-any-records, I now have a complete solution.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails code in the view is executed when the view is rendered. So rpt_month contains value returned by select_tag (not the value selected by user). To get the value selected by user, you will have to use client side scripting.

If I understand your problem correctly, *link_to* is not really required. You could just do this:

```
<%= form_tag(bentries_path, method: "get") do %>
  <%= select_tag(:billDate, options_for_select((1..12).map{|m| [Date::MONTHNAMES[m], m] }) ) %>
  <%= button_tag "Get Report" %>
<% end %>
```

In controller, you will have to modify your query to consider only month part of the date field. It is explained very well in the accepted answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624601/activerecord-find-by-year-day-or-month-on-a-date-field) question:

Comment: Thanks @Nitish.  That corrects my problem in obtaining the right month from the select, but I am, still having problems getting the query to pull the records in the controller.  I had previously seen your referenced post on how to get the month part of a date field.  But I must have something wrong in the code, because I am stll not getting any records returned and I have "bills" with a "billDate" containing the month which I am attempting to pull using the MonthlySumm page.