# Query in Rails not returning any records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

This is an extension of my previous question ([using a select, assign variable and retrieve records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158230/using-a-select-assign-variable-and-retrieve-records)).

I resolved the problem with passing the correct value to the controller, but my query still does NOT return any records, yet there ARE matching records in my database.

NEW edited controller for the app...

```
# GET /bentries/january
def monthlysumm
   @bentries = Bentry.by_month(params[:billDate])    
end
```

AND here is the addition to the model...

```
def self.by_month(mon)
   where("strftime('%m', billDate) + 0 = ?", mon)
end
```

This generates a SQL statement like this...

```
SELECT "bentries".* FROM "bentries" WHERE (strftime('%m", billDate) + 0 = '2')
```

If I go into SQLite Manager in Firefox and type (the equivalent) SQL statement of...

```
SELECT * FROM bentries WHERE (strftime('%m', billDate) + 0 = 2)
```

It returns the expected 3 records from the "bentries" table, but yet the code in app generates NO resulting recordset.

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong in the controller or model?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your queries are not the same.

The one generated is looking for a string, the one you are typing in is looking for an integer.

Parameters come into the controller as strings so you need to make it an integer if necessary.  For example:

```
def self.by_month(mon)
   where("strftime('%m', billDate) + 0 = ?", mon.to_i)
end
```

Or you can do it in the call to `by_month`, depending on whether you want the month in your `by_month` method to be an integer or a string.

Comment: Okay, I figured it was something like that.  Now I have added the `.to-i` as you suggest and _viola_ I now have the results I expected!  THANK YOU, Graeme!