# Rails scope filtering datetime param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, get, parameters

I built a rails app as API for a mobile app.
I would like to get a subset of the records based on GET parameters.

My model is like this:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: inspections
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  date       :date
#  station_id :integer
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#
class Inspection < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Filterable

  belongs_to :station
  has_many :state_checks

  scope :station_id, -> (station_id) { where station_id: station_id }
  scope :date, -> (date) { where date: DateTime.parse(date) }
end
```

Then I wrote a concern:

```
module Filterable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def filter(filtering_params)
      results = self.where(nil)
      filtering_params.each do |key, value|
         results = results.public_send(key, value) if value.present?
      end
      results
    end
  end
end
```

Now, when I do a GET '/inspections.json?station_id=1&date=2015-04-03T10:44:00.000Z'
the scope :station_id works but :date scope doesn't work.
Any clue about this?

Thanks

Comment: hey what do you have on the form?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like date is giving you a full timestamp. This is pretty much what your query is doing:

```
date_1 = DateTime.parse('2015-04-03T10:01:00.000Z')
-> 'Fri, 03 Apr 2015 10:01:00 +0000'
date_2 = DateTime.parse('2015-04-03T10:11:00.000Z')
-> 'Fri, 03 Apr 2015 10:11:00 +0000'
date_1 == date_2
-> false
```

Your query is checking for equality down to the second. Looks like you need something more like this: [ActiveRecord Find By Year, Day or Month on a Date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624601/activerecord-find-by-year-day-or-month-on-a-date-field)