# How to search model by date and day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

By using a railscast video i create a simple search that works on same model. And i have fields for date, day and time.

my model

```
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :washer, optional: true
  belongs_to :location, optional: true

  has_many :sale_services
  has_many :services, :through => :sale_services

  def day
    created_at.strftime('%A')
  end

  def time
    created_at.strftime("%H:%M")
  end

  def date
    created_at.strftime('%F')
  end


def self.search(search)
    if search
      key = "'%#{search}%'"
      columns = %w{ city station venue area country plate_number }
      joins(:services).joins(:washer).joins(:location).where(columns.map {|c| "#{c} ILIKE #{key}" }.join(' OR '))
    else
      where(nil)
    end
  end
end
```

What do i need to change to be sure i can search for day, and date on a timestamp field?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code as a reference, I have tried this on created_at field ant it works for me.

```
Model.where('extract(year  from date_column) = ?', desired_year)
Model.where('extract(month from date_column) = ?', desired_month)
Model.where('extract(day   from date_column) = ?', desired_day_of_month)
```

here is the [stackoverflowlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624601/activerecord-find-by-year-day-or-month-on-a-date-field) which you can review if above code doesn't work for you.