# How to filter users based on an exact year with date as a column in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to filter users using an SQL command on my model if the user is, for example, exactly 5 years old. How can I accomplish this? The range query works but removing the range does not return anything. 
**This works but I want it to output exactly with the age of 21 years old(if the birthdate is 1997/01/01) and it shouldn't include 22 years old.**

`users = users.where(["birthdate >= ? AND birthdate <= ?", 22.years.ago + 1.day, 21.years.ago])`

I've tried this one but it doesn't output anything: `users = users.where(["birthdate = ?", 21.years.ago])`

schema for users

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "email", default: "", null: false
t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
t.string "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.inet "current_sign_in_ip"
t.inet "last_sign_in_ip"
t.string "position"
t.string "employee_id"
t.string "first_name"
t.string "middle_name"
t.string "last_name"
t.string "gender"
t.string "address"
t.string "sss_number"
t.string "tin_number"
t.string "phil_health"
t.string "emergency_name"
t.string "emergency_contact"
t.date "birthdate"
t.date "date_hired"
t.string "role", default: "user"
t.integer "department_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
```

end

Comment: Could you post your schema for the users table?

Comment: `.where('birthdate BETWEEN ? AND ?', 22.years.ago + 1.day, 21.years.ago)` should work.

Comment: Try `users.where("birthdate >= ? AND birthdate <= ?", 22.years.ago + 1.day, 21.years.ago)`

Comment: You mean you want all users born in specific year?

Comment: is it possible if it's not range? just 21 years old only? like what marek said

Comment: This should work too: `.where(birthdate: (22.years.ago + 1.day)..21.years.ago)` You need a range, **not all people born in 1997 are actually 21**. Well, you can still build a method `_21_years_old` that returns a range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Range` and methods `beginning_of_year` and `end_of_year`, like this:

```
date = 22.years.ago #example
User.where(birthdate: date.beginning_of_year..date.end_of_year)
```

Comment: Two comments on this answer. 1. You can leave out the parentheses around the range. 2. You should replace the `...` (triple dots) with `..` (double dots). Triple dots will exclude the ending whereas double dots will include the ending. Since you end with `date.end_of_year` I assume you want to include the end of the year.

Comment: @JohanWentholt you're right, of course, I don't know what I was thinking about using 'exclusive' range. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I read again your post and I guess you are looking for users which birthday is a given date. They born today n years ago.
If it's that, one way could be setup some filter in your User model like:

```
def self.filter_year(year)
  where("cast(strftime('%Y', birthdate) as int) = ?", year)
end

def self.filter_month(month)
  where("cast(strftime('%m', birthdate) as int) = ?", month)
end

def self.filter_day(day)
  where("cast(strftime('%d', birthdate) as int) = ?", day)
end
```

Then call the filter as your will to get the collection of user:

```
users = User.filter_year(1997).filter_month(5).filter_day(9)
```

You get all user having their 21th birthday today.

Maybe there is a better way, maybe this is not what you are looking for.

But I hope this can help.

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9625690).

Comment: i have a question. This works only when the input  is birthday. How about if the input is only year?

Comment: If I get your point, you can just do `users = User.filter_year(1997)` to fetch all people born in 1997 or `users = User.filter_month(5)` to fetch all people born in May. And so on... This applies to the column birthdate of User. model. You can not get people born between two dates. For that you must follow the reply form Marek or comments to your question post.